# How to access a Imports like "typedef" declared in another file?

Tags: vb.net

I see that in VB.net I can define something like a typedef using the Imports statement:

```
Imports MyDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)))
```

Now I want to use this MyDict in some files of my project. Suppose the above statement is defined in MyForm.vb file, what should I do in AnotherForm.vb file to access this definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Imports` like this are just an alias for that specific file - they don't create a new "type".  You will need to copy the entire line into your other files if you want to use `MyDict` in the same way.

That being said, a three layer nested dictionary structure is something I'd consider making a custom type to handle.  This is a fairly complicated "dictionary", and having a custom type would allow you to potentially write your code in a cleaner, safer manner.

Comment: I agree. Time to refactor now.